# usage of "maximally"

Tags: word-choice

In the meaning of

> [select] at most 50 items.

What is the correct variant of `max... 50 items`? Why?

> maximally 50 items.
> maximal 50.
> a maximum of 50 items.
> ...

[This similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185272/when-to-use-the-abverbial-form-of-maximal-maximally) does not seem to provide answer with numbers involved.

Comment: I'd go with *a maximum of* or *at most* 50 items.

Comment: The previous question has a part-answer 'Maximally is usually found as an adverb that modifies an adjective, such as maximally efficient'. Though 'Select maximally 50 items' is arguably totally grammatical, and internet examples occur, 'Select at most 50 items' and 'Select a maximum of 50 items' are as Yosef implies far more idiomatic and sound far less rarefied. And 'rarefied' is heading for Orwell's taboo 'outlandish'.

Comment: A counter-example to 'dont use this adverb before a numeral': 'Each conversation was divided into basic clauses, defined as utterances that contain maximally (but not minimally) one main verb.
From the Cambridge English Corpus' [[CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/maximally)]. But the register is very formal. // ?? "You may have maximally 3 Curly Wurlys."

Comment: "Maximal" is also normally used in expressions such as "select a maximal solution", "select a maximal collection of...", rather than with numbers.

Comment: Why would you want to use any of these, when 'at most 50 items' is perfectly clear and more elegant?

Comment: maximally and minimally are not used with items. Because they require a verb or adjective. Also, context would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The correct variant would be "a maximum of 50 items."

While "maximally" is a word, it is typically used to describe the manner or degree in which something is done or exists, rather than specifying a quantity. "Maximal" is an adjective that means the greatest or highest possible, but in this context, it is not commonly used to specify a quantity.

"A maximum of 50 items" accurately conveys the idea that the selection should not exceed the quantity of 50 items.

Answer (score 0):

Normally adverb **maximally** in context means "to the greatest degree possible", which is not the same thing as "an imposed finite limit", the meaning of "at most 50" and "a maximum of 50".

**maximally** needs to modify an adjective which admits degree, and an imposed finite limit  (e.g. 50) is not a matter of degree.

Answer (score 0):

maximally and minimally are not used be used here because **they require a verb OR adjective**.

Standard usage for this kind of context is:

- a maximum of 50 items [in writing it out]
- 50 items (maximum).

The second is used in lists to avoid a and of.

- Select 50 items (maximum)

Comment: **maximally** requires an adjective that admits degree. maximally flat, effective, tolerated, etc.

Comment: @TimR He was maximally marginalized in that society. He was marginalized to the greatest degree possible in that society.  A verb or adjective. They were minimally compromised. I added adjective. The point being it cannot be used on its own. And it is not due to meaning that it cannot be used.